# Fall back if site is down

Tags: website, host

Alright so I was just wondering how one would go about setting up a system that points to a different server if your main server goes down. In our instance we host a site on Windows Azure, but when Azure goes down, it would be nice to be able to quickly point to a site hosted internally or externally that says something like "Site is down", without having to wait for DNS records to update.

So I guess I was wondering if there are any good solutions people have found for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up some sort of software load balancer and put your actual server(s) behind the lb virtual ip.

Then when the sites are down (if you have no redundancy), the vip can point to a downpage, which can be hosted by something really simple such a tiny instance of amazon ec2 spun up just for this purpose.

This is much faster than dns change propagation. You can also automate the process.

Comment: Keep in mind you could just put some HTML/CSS up on S3 and serve them from that.